# CORS Node.js in chrome browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, cors, backend

I am using Heroku and netlify to host

> https://n-blogcode.netlify.app/

Now I m using cors in backend and it needed to be switched on using a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf) on my pc for the cards section to work.

But not everyone will know to enable cors access through extension to see my website. So how do I make it so everyone can directly see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the npm [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package in your nodejs program, and place your netlify origin on the [allowed list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuring-cors).

Something like this might work.

```js
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://n-blogcode.netlify.app'
}

...

app.use(cors(corsOptions))           //cors for all routes
app.options('*', cors())             //cors for preflight requests
```

This causes your nodejs program to include the appropriate CORS headers in its responses to requests from your html / js code hosted on netlify.

You definitely don't want to require a web extension for your users. If you do, you won't have many users. :-)

Answer (score 1):

before resolving the CORS error you have to understand how it works, quoted by IBM.com:

> CORS is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP header to inform a
> browser to allow a web application running at one origin (domain) have
> permission to access selected resources from a server at a different
> origin

consider an API which is for ABC Bank, a hacker want to send some request to this API but with your account, if CORS does not exist, the hacker simply could write a malware code something like this:

```
Axios.post("https://bankABC.com/api/MoneyTransfer?to=123456789");
```

and puts this script on a third-party website.
when you open that site, the hacker can steal all your money!

but fortunately, the CORS mechanism was implemented in our browsers to prevent such undesirable cross-domain requests, to define which origin can send requests to a special route, you have to set that in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in your response header. there is a middleware called [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors), which you can use to define this header...

Answer (score 0):

If you're want to handle multiple origins:

```
let whitelist = [
  process.env.WEB_URL,
  process.env.ROOT_API,
  process.env.SOCKET_URL
]

let corsOptions = {
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Origin not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  }
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```